# Count lines where the second field starts with a specific character

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file that looks like this

```
header start
stuff
header end
pos LV file LVG size
1   a1 AAA  BBB 100
2   b1 AAC  BBB 1000
3   a3 AAB  BBB 47
4   b6 AAC  BBB 1000
```

I need to count the lines that start with `a` on second column.
Googling I got to this

```
awk '/LVG/{p=$0} {a[p]++} END{for(i in a) print i"\n"a[i]-1}' file
```

But I need to filter stuff so the output is only the line count.
I added the following

```
awk '/LVG/ || $2 ~ "^a"' file | awk '/LVG/{p=$0} {a[p]++} END{for(i in a) print i"\n"a[i]-1}' | tail -1
```

This does what I need, but I was wondering if all this could be done with a single `awk` command.

Comment: Basically you want to count all lines where the second column starts with `a`?

Comment: So what output are you expecting? Just the  number `2`? Your awk doesn't make sense to me, with the input you show, that awk command would only look at the header and none of the data lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most basic requirement is met via

```
awk '$2~/^a/{c++} END{print c+0}'
```

This will inspect the second column; check if it starts with `a` via regexp comparison, and increase a counter `c`. At end-of-file it will print the counter. In order to ensure that a number is printed even if `c` is never actually increased, we print `c+0` which will not change `c` if it is already non-zero, but force interpretation as a number when `c` is still uninitialized.

Now to ensure that no "stray" token from the "header" part interfere, a first check is to ensure the first column is an integer:

```
awk '$1+0==$1 && $2~/^a/{c++} END{print c+0}'
```

The idea is here that `$1+0` will be interpreted arithmetically as "adding nothing" if `$1` is a number but would instruct `awk` to *append the character `0`* if it is "text", hence `$1+0` will be unchanged only if `$1` is a number.

For an even more sophisticated check, we can inhibit considering lines until the "header end" line is encountered, and in addition skip the line immediately after that, too:

```
awk 'f==2&&$2~/^a/{c++} f==1&&NF{f++} $0=="header end"{f=1} END{print c+0}'
```

This will set a flag `f` to 1 when the `header end` line is encountered, set it to `2` on the first non-empty line after the header, and only in lines where `f` is `2` check the second column.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a not `awk` solution but `grep` one, relying on the records structure:

```bsh
$ grep "^[0-9]\+[[:blank:]]\+a[0-9]\+[[:blank:]]\+[A-Z]\+[[:blank:]]\+[A-Z]\+[[:blank:]]\+[0-9]\+$" file | wc -l
2
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I was looking for a awk which allows some math with no aditional commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==1 ,/^header end$/ { next };
    !skip_hdr              { skip_hdr=1; next }
    ($2 ~ /^a/)            { count++ }
END{ print count+0 }' infile
```

- `NR==1 ,/^header end$/ { next }`:
  skips lines from the beginning of the file up-to the first line that is `header end`; this skips below lines:

  ```
  header start
  stuff
  header end
  ```
- `!skip_hdr { skip_hdr=1; next }`:
  skips title-header line *`pos LV file LVG size`*.
- `($2 ~ /^a/) { count++ }`:
  counts lines that their second column begin with a `a` character (case-insensitive).
- `END{ print count+0 }`:
  print the final count value.

Comment: Rather than using `header ends` you could use `LVG` as the user does. You get a slightly shorter piece of code then: `awk 'NR==1,/LVG/ { next } $2 ~ /^a/ { ++c } END { print c }' file`

Comment: thanks, I used that because there might be something in _`stuff`_ that can match `LVG` there and probably calculate a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple solutions

To meet your description: *count the lines that start with a on second column* this is enough:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^a/ { count++ } END {print count}' file
```

It is even possible with a grep (should be faster) command:

```
grep -c '^[0-9][0-9]* *a' test.txt
```

Which also happens to be more specific as it requires that the first field is a number (assuming that is what you need from the example posted) and the field delimiter is an space.

## Looking deeper

But the first solution you posted:

```
awk '/LVG/{p=$0} {a[p]++} END{for(i in a) print i"\n"a[i]-1}' file
```

Does something quite different.

On this file input:

```
> cat file
header start
stuff
header end
pos1 LV file LVG size
1   a1 AAA  BBB 100
2   b1 AAC  BBB 1000
3   a3 AAB  BBB 47
4   b6 AAC  BBB 1000
5   c9 BBA  CBA 20
pos2 LV file LVG size
1   a1 AAA  BBB 100
2   b1 AAC  BBB 1000
pos3 LV file LVG size
1   a1 AAA  BBB 100
2   b1 AAC  BBB 1000
3   a3 AAB  BBB 47
```

The code you posted prints a result for each (diferent) header:

```
> awk '/LVG/{p=$0} {a[p]++} END{for(i in a) print i"=="a[i]-1}' test.txt 
==2
pos1 LV file LVG size==5
pos3 LV file LVG size==3
pos2 LV file LVG size==2
```

That is: 2 lines for the empty header, 5 lines after the header "pos1", etc....

I do not know if you need this kind of count or not. Nor am I clear about why you subtract 1 from the count.

The only additional requirement is to only count lines on which the second field starts with an `a`

```
$ awk '/LVG/{p=$0} $2 ~ /^a/ {a[p]++} END{for(i in a) print i"=="a[i]}' test.txt
pos1 LV file LVG size==2
pos3 LV file LVG size==2
pos2 LV file LVG size==1
```

If you also need the first field to be a number (similar to the grep command above):

```
$ awk '/LVG/{p=$0} ($1+0!=0)&&($2~/^a/) {a[p]++} END{for(i in a) print i"=="a[i]}' test.txt
pos1 LV file LVG size==2
pos3 LV file LVG size==2
pos2 LV file LVG size==1
```